# GAMM with BETAR(Link = "Logit")

Tags: r, beta-regression, gamm4

I'm trying to use betar in gamm4 models but keep hitting an error. As far as I can tell, betar is one of the families that should be available - can anyone identify why I would keep hitting this error?

```
mod.gamm.2015 <- gamm4(tsdata ~ s(sgbio), random = ~(1|AnimalID), family = betar(link = "logit"), data = modeldata.2015)
```

Receiving the following error

```
Error in as(value, fieldClass, strict = FALSE) : 
  internal problem in as(): “extended.family” is(object, "family") is TRUE, but the metadata asserts that the 'is' relation is FALSE
```

Comment: You can't use the `betar()` family with anything but `gam()` and `bam()`. With `gamm4::gamm4()` you are limited to the families supported by `lme4::glmer()`